# How to automatically process sqlite export to get JSON that reflect relations DB?

Tags: json, sqlite, underscore.js, export-to-csv, jq

I'm exporting data from a [sqlite database](https://github.com/Labx/LibraryBox-app/blob/7c612c65d60846d801154a8eefcfb18e10c3a833/app/data/data.sqlite3?raw=true) (no choice here) to generate a JSON for an AngulaJS app.

### JSON export from SQLite

`sqlite3` CSV export **flatten the relational structure and add duplication**:

```json
[
  {
    "bid": 5, // book id
    "aid": 4,  // author's id
    "tags": 3,
    "title": "Jacques le fataliste et son maître",
  },
  {
    "bid": 5,
    "aid": 23, // same book another author
    "tags": 8, // same book another tag
    "title": "Jacques le fataliste et son maître",
  }
  …
]
```

#### SQLite to JSON command

The [sqlite database](https://github.com/Labx/LibraryBox-app/blob/7c612c65d60846d801154a8eefcfb18e10c3a833/app/data/data.sqlite3?raw=true) is available on the github and the command I use to export/convert is:

```shell
sqlite3 -csv -header app/data/data.sqlite3 \
"SELECT b.id as bid, title, b.sort as sort_book, a.id as aid, a.sort as sort_author, path, name FROM books as b inner join books_authors_link as b_a ON b.id = b_a.book INNER JOIN authors as a ON a.id = b_a.author" \
| ./node_modules/csvtojson/bin/csvtojson \
> authors-books.json
```

### JSON Goal

I designed the final JSON with my customer in a document-oriented approach:

- all I need in an object ;
- references to other resources as

  - an *id*/*primary key* for forein key ;
  - a list of _id_s/*primary keys* for many-to-many relations.

Here is an example: of **my goal**:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "authors": [4, 23],
        "tags": [3,8,29,69],
        "title": "Jacques le fataliste et son maître",
        …
    }
    …
]
```

If you speak French, here is the [github issue from the project](https://github.com/Labx/LibraryBox-app/issues/8)

### Question

So how can I get this result using a command line pipe or javascript-based tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq`, you could do this.

Group the items by the key `bid` (and maybe `title`) and aggregate the authors and tags.

```
group_by(.bid) |
    map({
        bid:     .[0].bid,
        title:   .[0].title,
        authors: map(.aid),
        tags:    map(.tags)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your data and this code in node seems to do the trick. It uses lodash (a better underscore.js), I hope it qualifies for what you call javascript based tools :)

```js
var _ = require('lodash');

var arrayFields = [
  'aid'
];

var keysMap = {
  id: 'bid',
  authors: 'aid',
  tags: 'tags',
  title: 'title'
};

var result = _(rows)
  .groupBy('bid') // group the rows by id
  .map(function(rows) {
    // for each group, take the first instance of the row as a basis
    var row = _.clone(_.first(rows));
    // and collect all grouped row values for the interesting fields
    _.forEach(arrayFields, function(key) {
      row[key] = _.pluck(rows, key);
    })
    return row;
  })
  .map(function(row) {
    var obj = {};
    // build a row object with translated keys
    _.forEach(keysMap, function(originalKey, targetKey) {
      obj[targetKey] = row[originalKey];
    });
    return obj;
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

Here is the output :

```json
[ 
  { 
    id: 5,
    authors: [ 4, 23 ],
    tags: 3,
    title: 'Jacques le fataliste et son maître' 
  } 
]
```